# How do I add up different values in a list with condition?

Tags: c#, list, sum

I have a list which has countries and each country has a number.
Each country can appear again with a different number.

My job is to write out which country has the number one and how many times.

For example:

> England 1,
>   Germany 3,
>   Hungary 1,
>   Germany 1,
>   Sweeden 2,
>   Hungary 4,
>   French 2,
>   Hungary 1,
>   England 1,
>   England 1

The answer supposed to be look like this:

> "The number 1 appeared under Hungary 2 times"
>   "The number 1 appeared under England 3 times"

```
class countries
{
    public string country;
    public int number

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region Beolvasás
        List<countries> x = new List<countries>();
        StreamReader d = new StreamReader("focivb.txt", Encoding.Default);

        while (!d.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] s = d.ReadLine().Split('\t');

            countries a = new countries();

            a.country= s[0];
            a.number= Convert.ToInt32(s[1]);


            x.Add(a);
        }
        d.Close();
    }
}
```

the .txt looks like basically the same except it is separated by tabulator

Comment: `foreach (var item in  x.Where(c => c.number ==1).GroupBy(c => c.country)){Console.WriteLine("The number 1 appeared under {0} {1} times", item.Key, item.Count());}`

Answer (score 0):

Use linq and group by name and number then count data.
My snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class CountryNumber
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new List<CountryNumber> {
                new CountryNumber { Country = "England", Number = 1},
                new CountryNumber { Country = "Germany", Number = 3},
                new CountryNumber { Country = "Hungary", Number = 1},
                new CountryNumber { Country = "Germany", Number = 1},
                new CountryNumber { Country = "Sweeden", Number = 1},
                new CountryNumber { Country = "Hungary", Number = 4},
                new CountryNumber { Country = "French", Number = 2},
                new CountryNumber { Country = "Hungary", Number = 1},
                new CountryNumber { Country = "England", Number = 1},
                new CountryNumber { Country = "England", Number = 1}
            };

            var groupped = data.GroupBy(d => new { Country = d.Country, Number = d.Number });

            foreach (var one in groupped) { 
              Console.WriteLine($"{one.Key.Country}, {one.Key.Number}: {one.Count()}");
            }                        
        }
    }
}
```